# I need a regex to remove space before a specific character

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I need a regex to remove all space before a specific character.

#### Exemple:

Remove all space before the first " - "

Before:

```
My Beautiful Video - Hello darling - 19.10.2015 10:00
```

After:

```
MyBeautifulVideo - Hello darling - 19.10.2015 10:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `(*SKIP)(*F)` or capturing group.

```
preg_replace('~ - .*(*SKIP)(*F)| ~', '', $str);
```

syntax of the above regex control verb must be like,

```
What_I_want_to_avoid(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|What_I_want_to_match
```

So `- .*` part should match all the chars from the first space hyphen space to the last. Now the control verb `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail. Now the regex after the OR operator will do matching only from the remaining string. It won't work if you use  `.*`, `.*?` in the alternate branch.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

or

```
preg_replace('~( - .*)| ~', '\1', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lO0hF8/1)

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lO0hF8/2)

Comment: I wish more RegEx answers would include an explanation of how and why they work.  It is better to teach people to fish.

Comment: @EricJ. give some time to add explanations.

Comment: Wounderful it's work's with **preg_replace('~( - .*)| ~', '\1', $str)**

Answer (score 1):

```
\s*-.*$\K|\s
```

You can use `\K` here and replace by empty string.

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/8)

```
$re = '/\s*-.*$\K|\s/m'; 
$str = "My Beautiful Video - Hello darling - 19.10.2015 10:00"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: The regex uses `\K`, while the demo code uses `(*SKIP)(*F)`.