# Combine three functions into one function to remove all possible spaces around a specific character and a digit(s)

Tags: regex, vba

**Note:** Before I post my question,
I got a suggestion that this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220384/i-need-a-regex-to-remove-space-before-a-specific-character) to answer my question, I have checked it and **it dose not**.

Because there are more than one user input values on our database system (later exported into an Excel spreadsheet).
So the manual entry of multiplication pattern by users occurs to be different each time.
example 1:  **"3 x2"**
example 2:  **"4x 8"**
example 3:  **"6 x 10"**
as you will notice there may be a space between "X" character and the digits in a different position each time.
Because my expertise with regular expression is on the beginning stages,
I have been created three functions to deal with each example above and they works respectively correctly as it should.
But, I seek to combine these function into one function (if it is possible) for easier use.
In Advance, great thanks for your help.

| Current Values | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| Last the 3 x2 Injection | Last the 3x2 Injection |
| Last the 4x 8 Injection | Last the 4x8 Injection |
| Last the 6 x 10 Injection | Last the 6x10 Injection |

```
Function Remove_Space_between_Digit_X(ByVal str As String) As String
   Static reg As New RegExp
     reg.Global = True
      reg.IgnoreCase = True
      
       reg.Pattern = "(\s[0-9]+)(\s)(x)"
       
    Remove_Space_between_Digit_X = re.Replace(str, "$1$3")
End Function

Function Remove_Space_between_X_Digit(ByVal str As String) As String
   Static reg As New RegExp
     reg.Global = True
      reg.IgnoreCase = True
      
       reg.Pattern = "(x)(\s)([0-9]+)(\s)"
       
    Remove_Space_between_X_Digit = reg.Replace(str, "$1$3$4")
End Function

Function Remove_Space_around_X_Digit(ByVal str As String) As String
   Static reg As New RegExp
     reg.Global = True
      reg.IgnoreCase = True
      
       reg.Pattern = "([0-9])+(\s)(x)(\s)([0-9]+)(\s)"
       
    Remove_Space_around_X_Digit = reg.Replace(str, "$1$3$5$6")
End Function
```

Comment: Please try `reg.Pattern = "\b(\d+)\s*(x)\s*(\d+)\b"` and `reg.Replace(str, "$1$2$3")` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(\d)\s*x\s*(\d)
```

which will match:

- `(\d)` : a digit (captured in group 1)
- `\s*x\s*` : an `x` surrounded by some number of spaces
- `(\d)` : a digit (captured in group 2)

and replace it with `$1x$2` to remove any spaces in the string.

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/orwIZf/1)

In VBA:

```vb
Function Remove_Space_around_X(ByVal str As String) As String
    Static reg As New RegExp
    reg.Global = True
    reg.IgnoreCase = True 
    reg.Pattern = "(\d)\s*x\s*(\d)"
       
    Remove_Space_around_X = reg.Replace(str, "$1x$2")
End Function
```

**Note**

In the interest of simplicity the regex is not as strict as it could be; it will also match something like `a4 x 3b`. If this could be an issue, please instead use:

```
\b(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)\b
```

which uses word breaks and matches multiple digits to ensure that it *only* matches multiplications of numbers.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DykR4h/1)

Comment: @hope good to hear. Please do read the note I've added to the answer as it may impact your usage.

Answer (score 1):

- Base on your sample data, it can be done with an UDF
- Support other operators, eg. `4 * 5` or `2 + 4`. In the 2nd option, you need to modify `aKey` as needed.

```vb
Function Remove_Space(ByVal sStr As String) As String
    Static reg As New RegExp
    Dim objmatch As Object
    reg.Global = True
    reg.IgnoreCase = True
    reg.Pattern = "\d+\D+\d+"
    Set objmatch = reg.Execute(sStr)
    If objmatch.Count > 0 Then
        sStr = Replace(sStr, objmatch(0), Replace(objmatch(0), " ", ""))
    End If
    Remove_Space = sStr
End Function
```

- If `x` is the only operator between two numbers, you can do it w/o RegExp.

```vb
Function RemoveSpace(ByVal sTxt As String) As String
    Dim aKey, i As Long
    aKey = Array(" x ", " x", "x ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(aKey)
        sTxt = Replace(sTxt, aKey(i), "x", , , vbTextCompare)
    Next
    RemoveSpace = sTxt
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to take:
any two numbers with only a single "x" and zero or more spaces around the "x"

...and convert that to:
the original two numbers with an explicit " x " between them.

This regular expression matches all the cases that you provided, as well as something like "7x23" (no spaces at all).

```
([0-9]+) *x *([0-9]+)
```

Meaning:

- "([0-9]+)" is the first number (a sequence of numerals from 0 to 9)
- " *" means zero or more literal spaces
- "x" means a literal x
- " *" means zero ore more literal spaces
- "([0-9]+)" is the second number (a sequence of numerals from 0 to 9)

The replacement regex pattern is simply:

```
\1 x \2
```

Meaning:

- "\1" the first regex grouping (a regex surrounded by parentheses)
- " x " a literal <SPACE>-x-<SPACE>
- "\2" the second regex grouping (a regex surrounded by parentheses)

Based on your example code, I presume that your replacement string would be:

```
"$1 x $2"
```

--klode